Tessellation of figures
I'm currently pondering the following problem: "In how many equal parts can I divide a figure?" The minimum unit is the square, so diagonal lines cannot be drawn. I have solved it for these two figures, and it can indeed be done for numbers that are divisors of the total area of these figures. I've noticed that there are certain issues with some concave figures. I wonder if someone could help me or guide me to see the mathematics behind this. I suspect that isometric transformations are involved, but I also believe there might be something deeper, such as group theory.Tessellations of some figures With areas of 24 and 20 respectively"

In general these tiling problems can be difficult. It's not hard to find examples where an equal division is impossible.
For example, the figure below, with area $10$, can't be divided into five $2 \times 1$ tiles.

One way to see this is that if the figure is coloured in a checkerboard pattern, each tile must consist of a white square and a black square.  But there are $6$ white and $4$ white squares (or vice versa).
